# Check whether array is sorted recursively

Tags: java, array, sorting, recursion

I'm trying to implement `isSorted` method checking whether given array is sorted recursively. I've written two types, one is similar to merge sort logic, the another is like loop. Can they be made more efficient? Is there any thing I overlooked?

```
class SortedRecursive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(9, 9, 9));
        List<Integer> test2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(9, 10, 11));
        List<Integer> test3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 5, 3, 7));
        List<Integer> test4 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,2,3,3,4));


        System.out.println("test(nlogn) -> " + isSorted(test));
        System.out.println("test(n) -> " + isSortedAnotherVersion(test, 0));
        System.out.println("test2(nlogn) -> " + isSorted(test2));
        System.out.println("test2(n) -> " + isSortedAnotherVersion(test2, 0));
        System.out.println("input(nlogn) -> " + isSorted(test3));
        System.out.println("input(n) -> " + isSortedAnotherVersion(test3, 0));
        System.out.println("output(nlogn) -> " + isSorted(test4));
        System.out.println("output(n) -> " + isSortedAnotherVersion(test4, 0));
    }

    public static boolean isSorted(List<Integer> arr) {
        if (arr == null || arr.size() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (arr.size() == 1) {
            return true;
        }


        int middleIndex = arr.size() / 2 ;
        List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> right = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < middleIndex; i++) {
            left.add(arr.get(i));
        }

        for (int i = middleIndex; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            right.add(arr.get(i));
        }

        //System.out.println("left -> " + left + " right -> " + right);

        boolean result = left.get(middleIndex - 1) <= right.get(0);

        return isSorted(left) && result && isSorted(right);

    }

    public static boolean isSortedAnotherVersion(List<Integer> arr, int index) {
        if (arr.size() == 1 || index == arr.size() - 1)
            return true;
        if (arr.get(index) > arr.get(index + 1)) return false;
        return isSortedAnotherVersion(arr, index + 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: added the another version mentioned @MikeBorkland

Comment: Looks good! It should be quite a bit faster for very large `n`.

Comment: I wonder why you want a recursive method at all, if the same can be achieved with a simple loop.

Comment: @MartinR I think this is OK as an exercise to practice recursion and the principles of divide and conquer. But you are definitely right: in real life this should not be done recursively.

Comment: Yes, abosultely for practising @mtj

Comment: @MikeBorkland I don't think your initial remark about the first solution being \$O(n\cdot\log(n))\$ (which is no longer there, maybe due to the question having been deleted and re-opened) is correct. First, the number of splits into sub-lists is not \$log(n)\$ but \$n\$, because both sub-lists are re-split and not only one. And also, it's not like the list is split into \$n\$ sublists for every list element, but only once. So the time complexity of splitting the list just adds to the complexity of comparing element pairs instead of multiplying it, making the overall time complexity \$O(n)\$.

Comment: @MikeBorkland Never mind, I think I see what you mean now. Since the first solution copies every list element on a split instead of calling `List.sublist`, which just creates a view of the original list, the split is not a constant-time operation but proportional to the size of the list to be split. So every element in the original has to be copied \$\log(n)\$ times, making the total number of element copies \$n\cdot\log(n)\$.

Comment: @Stingy The recurrence is the same as merge sort: `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(n)`. This is the worst case, as short-circuiting could prevent some of the recursive calls from being made. The solution to the recurrence is `Θ(n lg n)`. Another way to look at it is that there are approximately lg n levels in the recursion tree, with all the components in each level doing a combined `Θ(n)` amount of work (this comes from the `for` loops to fill the auxiliary arrays). Informally, we can then conclude the same answer by multiplying `Θ(n)` by lg n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Version 1:**

Basically OK, but the copying of elements to another list is unnecessary. Have a look at `List.sublist` on how to create lists from a given index range.

Additionally, you should change the return statement to `result && isSorted(left) && isSorted(right)` so that the recursion does not take place if result is already false. (Look up short-circuiting in logical statements.)

**Version 2:**

*NO.* It is much better not to copy the elements and use indexes into the unmodified structure, but here you recurse for every element in the list, i.e. the recursion depth equals the list size. This is a total no-go, as it will definitely blow your stack if we are talking about serious data sizes.

Nevertheless, explore the option of using indexes (maybe a start-index AND an end-index) into the given structure some more and combine it to a divide and conquer-approach as in your first solution.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

An array `a` is sorted if `a[i] <= a[i+1]` for `0 <= i < a.size() - 1`.
For an *empty* array that is a [“vacuous truth”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) – there are no indices 
satisfying the condition.

Therefore your functions should return `true` for an empty array.

Your first function returns `false` for an empty array, and the second
one crashes with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**More remarks:**

- Your function takes a `List` as parameter, i.e. it can not only be
  called with an `ArrayList` but also with other lists (like `LinkedList`)
  for which each `get(i)` has to traverse the list from the head
  up to position `i`.

  I'd suggest to either take an *array* parameter, or to modify it to
  *iterate* over the elements instead.
- I do not see an advantage of any recursion. The same task can be 
  achieved with a simple loop.
- You could make the function *generic,* so that it can not only be
  used with integer arrays/lists, but also with other (comparable) 
  types.